# Why app's database not copied to android device?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a simple dictionary app that uses this database handler class.
( I've already filled the database using DB Browser and want to ship it with the app)

```
public class DictionaryDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "dict.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.dictshop.dict/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE_DICTIONARY = "dictionary";
    private static final String FIELD_WORD = "word";
    private static final String FIELD_DEFINITION = "definition";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Context myContext;


    DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }


    public void crateDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean vtVarMi = isDatabaseExist();

        if (!vtVarMi) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean isDatabaseExist() {
        SQLiteDatabase kontrol = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            kontrol = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            kontrol = null;
        }

        if (kontrol != null) {
            kontrol.close();
        }
        return kontrol != null ? true : false;
    }



    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                "(_id integer PRIMARY KEY," +
                FIELD_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                FIELD_DEFINITION + " TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Handle database upgrade as needed
    }

    public void saveRecord(String word, String definition) {
        long id = findWordID(word);
        if (id>0) {
            updateRecord(id, word,definition);
        } else {
            addRecord(word,definition);
        }

    }

    public long addRecord(String word, String definition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FIELD_WORD, word);
        values.put(FIELD_DEFINITION, definition);
        return db.insert(TABLE_DICTIONARY, null, values);
    }
    public int updateRecord(long id, String word, String definition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("_id", id);
        values.put(FIELD_WORD, word);
        values.put(FIELD_DEFINITION, definition);
        return db.update(TABLE_DICTIONARY, values, "_id = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
    public int deleteRecord(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_DICTIONARY, "_id = ?", new
                String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public long findWordID(String word) {
        long returnVal = -1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE " + FIELD_WORD + " = ?", new String[]{word});
        Log.i("findWordID","getCount()="+cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public String getWord(long id) {
        String returnVal = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT word FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE _id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public String getDefinition(long id) {
        String returnVal = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT definition FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE _id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public Cursor getWordList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT _id, " + FIELD_WORD +
                " FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY + " ORDER BY " + FIELD_WORD +
                " ASC";
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
}
```

I have pushed `dict.db` to the project:

```
me@pc:~$ ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554  push /home/me/Desktop/Dict/dict.db  /data/data/com.dictshop.Dict/databases/dict.db
```

and the app works fine on emulator, that is, I see the data are being displayed.

However, when I try the app on devices (one rooted, one unrooted) no data is being displayed. What could be wrong here?

I've tried different tricks to make this class work. This is my first app and I'm stock on this for days. So really appreciate your hints.

UPDATE: here is the MainActivity that uses the uses the database:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mEditTextWord;
    EditText mEditTextDefinition;
    DictionaryDatabase mDB;
    ListView mListView;

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
          // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
          ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
          // Enable the Up button
          ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDB = new DictionaryDatabase(this);




        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
                    view, int position, long id) {
                String nextId = String.valueOf(id+1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key" ,mDB.getWord(id)+"");
                intent.putExtra("value",mDB.getDefinition(id)+"");
                intent.putExtra("nextId",nextId+"");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Records deleted = " + mDB.deleteRecord(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateWordList();
                return true;
            }
        });
        updateWordList();

    }


    private void saveRecord() {
        mDB.saveRecord(mEditTextWord.getText().toString(),
                mEditTextDefinition.getText().toString());
        mEditTextWord.setText("");
        mEditTextDefinition.setText("");
        updateWordList();
    }

    private void updateWordList() {
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new
                SimpleCursorAdapter( this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mDB.getWordList(),
                new String[]{"word"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);
        mListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share_app:

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is the app");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);

                return true;


            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error message? logcat?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you pushed dict.db to the devices. So why would you expect to see it there?

Comment: @NabinKhadka I see no error in the console. Not sure what is logcat.

Comment: try run command chmod 777 in file on device to override....

Comment: @DanielK No I don't push `dict.db` manually (i.e using `adb`) to the device, because the code is supposed to do that. After all, when I upload the app to google play, I can not push the db to each user's device manually. Right? or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Well you say you pushed dict.db to your emulator... so I am assuming it had data & that data was displayed correctly. However, you're not pushing it to the devices so then you wouldn't have data to display. I was trying to clarify if you wanted an existing DB shipped with your app or if you were creating one yourself.

Comment: Can you post the class that you call the DB from? I managed to create your DB running your code for the helper class.

Comment: @DanielK I added my `MainActivity`. To clarify: I've already filled the database using `DB Browser` and want to ship it with the app.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLiteAssetHelper is what you want. Do the following:

Add the dependency to your app module's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}
```

Copy the database into the assets directory, in a subdirectory called `assets/databases`. So:

```
assets/databases/dict.db
```

Create a class:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dict.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

For reference: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: I briefly tried `sqliteassethelper`. It broke my app, so I decided to stay away form it. IMHO, its an extra hassle rather than a solution. However if you could wrap it around my existing class, I'll happily try it.

Comment: I see, well another proposed solution is that you place your pre-populated DB in the assets folder & then copy it to the regular database directory. See [this](http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). In fact, your code seems pretty similar to theirs, however, you never actually called `createDatabase()` in `onCreate()`. Try that.

Comment: Right, but I don't know how to call `crateDatabase() inside my MainActivity. I've tried different things but always get error. Can you help about this please?

Comment: `mDB.crateDatabase()` gives you errors? If so what errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is example sqlite local

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.dictshop.dict/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "dict.db";
private final Context context;

public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * copy database from assets to the device if not existed
**/
public boolean isCreatedDatabase() throws IOException {
    // Default is database have data
    boolean result = true;
    // check data 
    if (!checkExistDataBase()) {
         this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
            result = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }

    }
    return result;
}


/**
 * check database exist on the device?
 */
private boolean checkExistDataBase() {

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File fileDB = new File(myPath);
        if (fileDB.exists()) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * copy database from assets folder to the device
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

in MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    // create DB
    isCreateDB();
}

/*
 * Copy db from asset to database
 */
private boolean isCreateDB() {
    SqliteHelper data = new SqliteHelper(this);
    try {

        return data.isCreatedDatabase();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error Copy data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Hope. It will help you !!!